# How to detect if a UIScrollView has been idle over 500ms?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, timer

I have a `UIScrollView` and I am planning to add some code in the delegate function

```
func scrollViewDidScroll()
```

to detect if the scroll view is not scrolling over 500ms, but if the scroll view is not scrolling, the function is not called.

How to add a timer for this case? Whenever it starts to scroll, timer starts. While scrolling, the timer resets. And if no reset for 500ms, the timer triggers.

Comment: Not sure I understand what the difficulty is? What have you tried? What are your specific issues? This is quite straightforward...

Comment: Also you have both Objective-C and Swift tags. Given the little bit of code provided, I guess you're using Swift rather than Objective-C. Please remote the redundant tag.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to check for a value change `UIControlEvents.ValueChanged`

employ this for the scrollview's properties, such as `didScrollToPercentageOffset`

> ```
> (0, 0) means that the scrollView is not scrolled. This is when contentOffset is (0, 0).
> (1, 1) means that the scrollView is scrolled to its maximum contentOffset both horizontally and vertically.
> (0, 0.5) (for example) means that the scroll view is not scrolled horizontally and is at 50% of it's maximum content offset vertically.
> ```

or use a timer with `scrollViewDidScroll`

Answer (score 0):

> Whenever it starts to scroll, timer starts. While scrolling, the timer resets. And if no reset for 500ms, the timer triggers.

You did it, what else do you need?

This is the `NSTimer` class reference:https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/